# Join array comma delimiter powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, join, printing, import

Im trying to join certain columns into a comma delimited array with powershell.

```
$userlist = Import-Csv C:\POS.csv | Where-Object {($_.StoreId -eq "4801") -and ($_.TouchPointID -eq "10")} 

$output123 = -join "$($userlist.Printer) $($userlist.CashDrawer)"

echo $output123
```

That gives me

```
Printer POS IBM4610-TF6 Cash Drawer POS IBM
```

But i want it

```
Printer POS IBM4610-TF6,Cash Drawer POS IBM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output123 ="$($userlist.Printer),$($userlist.CashDrawer)"
```

Comment: I was so close. Thanks so much!